# labelの文字を5秒後に変更したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

labelの文字を5秒後に変更したい（例、labelの文字が「あいうえお」だったら、５秒後に「かきくけこ」に変わる）方法を探しているのですが、見つかりません。
TextFieldの文字をLabelに表示したりするのは分かるのですが。
ご教授頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Swift4

Comment: 「TextFieldの文字をLabelに表示したりするのは分かる」と言うのでしたら、そのコードをお示しいただけないでしょうか。ご自身のコード例を示していただいた方が、回答が書きやすくなりますし、「自分でここまではできる」と言うのを具体的なコードで示した方が、より的確な回答をより早く得やすくなります。また先の質問につけたコメントには何の反応も示されていませんが、「意味のわからないことがある」と言ったことでも構いませんので、何らかの返信コメントを付けることはできないでしょうか?ご自身の書かれた質問にはコメントをつけることができるはずです。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。TextFieldの文字をlabelに表示する　コードは　 textLabel.text = textFieldA.text です。スタックオーバーフローをあまり使わないので回答の見方が分かりませんでした。以後スタックオーバーフロの使い方を学び、返信や回答の確認などを迅速に行いたいと思います。申し訳ありませんでした。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: コードをお示しいただくときは行単位ではなく、もっと大きな塊、今の例でしたら、`textLabel`が`@IBOutlet`で`UILabel`につながっていること、その行は何かのアクションメソッドの中で実行されていること、などが分かった方が良いですね。ちなみに回答を書くのに必要・有用な情報は質問本文を編集していただいて本文にコードの形で掲載していただくと、多くの読者に読みやすくなりますし、コードをプロジェクトにコピーするだけで試せると、それを元に回答を作れるので、より多くの方が回答を考えてくれることにつながります。かなり以前のご質問でいまだに回答が得られていないものがあるようですが、コードが掲載されていないため敬遠されたのではないかと思います。折角本文を編集してもらったようですが、コードがないまま言葉を重ねて説明しようとしているので、あまり明確になったようには見えません…。簡単なサンプルプロジェクトを作り、そのコード全体(完全には動かなくても良い)を示していただいた上で「この部分をどうしたら良いのかわからない」とか「この部分でエラーが出てしまう」という形式の質問にすると、比較的早く回答が得られる傾向があります。最後に、私みたいなコメントはあくまであなたにも今後の読者にも、このサイトを有用に使っていただくためのアドバイスですので、あまり恐縮せずに、できることから取り入れてみて下さい。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。一度出来る限りのサンプルプロジェクトを作り、後日サンプルプロジェクトをもとに質問をしたいと思います。貴重なご指摘、アドバイスありがとうございます。真摯に受けてて良いプログラマーとして成長出来るよう頑張ります。至らない点が多く申し訳ありませんでした。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただこちらのご質問に関しては、それほど自由度は大きくないので、いただいたコメントに基づいてただいま回答を作成中です。もう一方のご質問については、作られたプロジェクトのコードを丸ごと示してもらった方が良いので、そちらの方は是非プロジェクトを作ってみて下さい。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。もう一方はプロジェクトを作り、後日質問しようと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずは前提ですが、この程度のプロジェクトは「コードの意味がわかるし、自分でXcodeのテンプレから作成することができる」と言うことでよろしいでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        textLabel.text = "あいうえお"
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        textLabel.text = textField.text
    }

}
```

※画像の挿入もコード整形も、質問を編集する時にも使える機能です。このように単純な例では画像なんてなくても大体想像がつくでしょうが、言葉を重ねるより1枚の画像を示した方がわかりやすそうな場合には、臆せずにその機能を利用して下さい。「投稿」や「保存」のボタンを押すまでは、プレビューエリアを見ながらあれこれ試して見られると良いと思います。

---

### `Timer`を使う方法

「5秒後に」何かを行う、と言った場合に一番よく使われる方法です。Objective-Cだけの時代からあるクラス(Objective-Cでの名前は`NSTimer`)ですが、近年Swiftから使いやすいメソッドも追加され、いまでも多用されています。

上記の`buttonPressed(_:)`メソッドを以下のように書き換えてみて下さい。

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false) {_ in
        self.textLabel.text = self.textField.text
    }
}
```

呼んでいるのは[`scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`というメソッド](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer)なのですが、最後の`block:`に与える引数は[SwiftのTrailing Closureの書き方](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)をしているので、`)`の後ろで`block:`というラベルもなくなっています。

ちなみに最初の引数は`TimeInterval`型で、これは実は単に`Double`の別名なんですが、Appleのframeworkで`TimeInterval`型が使われている場合、単位は必ず「秒」になります。

実際にプロジェクトを作って動きを確かめて下さい。

---

### libdispatch(GCD)を使う方法

(私ら年寄りの感覚からすると)比較的最近使われるようになった方法です。libdispatchを使いこなしている方は、こちらの方がお好きな方が多いように思います。

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.textLabel.text = self.textField.text
    }
}
```

使っているのは、`DispatchQueue`クラスの[`asyncAfter(deadline:qos:flags:execute:)`メソッド](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300100-asyncafter)なのですが、中2つの`qos:`と`flags:`はデフォルト通りでいい場合は省略可(と言うかこんな単純な例では普通は省略します)、最後の`execute:`は、またTrailing Closureの構文を使用しています。

`.now() + 5`と言うのは`DispatchTime`型の引数を書くときに独特のものですが、`DispatchTime.now() + 5`をドット記法を使って型名の部分を省略したものです。「今+5」が「今から5秒後」を表しているので、慣れれば意味はわかりやすいですね。

---

注意点としては、上に挙げたような方法では時間の精度は100msec、つまりせいぜい0.1秒程度です。1フレーム単位の精度で画面を更新したい、なんて言う場合にはアニメーションやゲームに使われているテクニックが必要になり、難度がはるかに上がります。

「5秒後」なんてキーワードにネットで検索してみると、意外に良記事は見つかりませんでした。この回答を少しでも参考にしていただければ幸いです。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。ありがとうございます。